# SQL Server 2000 pagination help

Tags: sql-server, datatable, paging

I need help in converting the mysql 'limit' function to sql server 2000, as this db does not have the limit function.

i have two values which is the start row  and end row, can someone help me how i can do this in sql server 2000 the most efficient way.

Comment: This can be done more easily (and in better performing ways) in newer versions of SQl Server, can you upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

check this : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLServer2KPagingSorting.aspx

another example for you : https://web.archive.org/web/20210506081930/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041206-1.shtml